# declare python enum without value using name instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

Is there any way in python to declare an enum's variables without values?

The syntax that works:

```py
from enum import Enum
class Color(Enum):
  Red = 'Red'
  Blue = 'Blue'
  Green = 'Green'
```

Since for this case the enum values are the same as the variable names, I'd like to avoid duplication.

Something like this maybe:

```py
from enum import Enum
class Color(Enum):
  Red
  Blue
  Green
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why `enum.auto()` is a thing, so you don't need to write values explicitly.

```py
from enum import Enum, auto
class Color(Enum):
  Red = auto()
  Blue = auto()
  Green = auto()
```

You can also do `print(Color.Red.name)` to retrieve the name of the member :D

Comment: This however will provide numeric sequential values for the enumerations, not reflect their name.

Comment: @jsbueno why would you need enums to reflect their names? That's not how enums work, you use enum for example to state mode, or to compare stuff, like `if mode == Modes.STANDBY` etc.. you don't use their names at all, just as identifiers.

Comment: It is not me, it is what the OP asked for. But yes, soemtimes you just need this: a pickable, human readable , distinguished value that can be typed unquoted in text.  It is mote of a "name spaced constants" than an Enum, but it is very useful. To the point some languages have this feature built in the syntax itself.

Comment: @jsbueno then you can do `print(Color.Red.name)` or any `Color.`*`.name`.

Comment: Still hope that in a near future we can have a version of python or Enum where you can avoid  '= ...' similar to what is provided in the question